# Trying to get property of non-object when using $post->post_parent

Tags: posts

I have debug set to true and to display different banners I am using conditional tags such as:

```
<?php

if ( is_page( 'about' ) || '2' == $post->post_parent ) {    
    // the page is "About", or the parent of the page is "About"
    $bannerimg = 'about.jpg';

} elseif ( is_page( 'learning' ) || '56' == $post->post_parent ) {  
    $bannerimg = 'teaching.jpg';

} elseif ( is_page( 'admissions' ) || '15' == $post->post_parent ) { 
    $bannerimg = 'admissions.jpg';

} else { 
    $bannerimg = 'home.jpg'; // just in case we are at an unclassified page, perhaps the home page
}   

?>
```

This results in error like:

```
[24-Sep-2013 00:03:32] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in D:\Clients\project1\www.project1.dev\wp-content\themes\custom_v1\header.php on line 100
```

Removing $post->post_parent fixes the PHP notice. Can anyone let me know if am doing anything wrong?

**Location of this code:**

I am using code structure similar to above in my header.php file. This is not inside any post loop. The cost I pasted above is from http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

**Purpose of my code:**
Based on what page the user is, I need to display different banners. So every page and its sub-pages have the same banner.

```
if ( is_page('114') || $post->post_parent == '114' ) { }
```

Even above code generates the error. Not sure why $post->post_parentis not considered an object.

Comment: Please explain the context. Where is this code? The short but not very helpful answer is that `$post` is not an object. The real question, the important question is "Why is it not an object?" Explaining the context should help answer that question.

Comment: Did you add global $post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**@kaiser** answer gives you the solution. I see from your comment that you don't understand, so I upvoted his answer and *translate* it in code:

```
<?php
$bannerimg = 'home.jpg';
$post = is_singular() ? get_queried_object() : false;
if ( ! empty($post) && is_a($post, 'WP_Post') ) {
  if ( 'about' == $post->post_name || '2' == $post->post_parent ) {    
    $bannerimg = 'about.jpg';
  } elseif ( 'learning' == $post->post_name || '56' == $post->post_parent) ) {  
    $bannerimg = 'teaching.jpg';
  } elseif ( 'admissions' == $post->post_name || '15' == $post->post_parent ) { 
    $bannerimg = 'admissions.jpg';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne. You saved my day. This worked and no errors.

Comment: +1 for the _translation_ :) Btw, as I normally use `instanceof` and only saw `is_a()` in WP core so far, I [read up the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017684/what-is-the-difference-between-is-a-and-instanceof) - maybe interesting for others as well.

Comment: I always used `is_a` because is shorten and I'm lazy. :) Now I read is slower in the future probably I'll try to use `instanceof`

Answer (score 4):

Normally `$post` *should* be an `object` which is an `instanceof WP_Post`. The [object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) normally has a default of `0` if

- no parent is set
- the post type is not hierarchical

So the only thing that can be here is that the post object isn't set up properly. Make sure you're inside a loop, have called `the_post()` or `$custom_query->the_post()` or used [`setup_postdata( $post );`](http://queryposts.com/function/setup_postdata/).

Btw, if you have `if/elseif/else`, you normally could avoid the else as it's similar to the default in a `switch`. Just set `$bannerimg = 'foo';` before the `if`.

Comment: Hey @kaiser. Thank you for the quick reply. I am unable to understand why this is happening. Also like you said I do have if/elseif/else statement.

Comment: Thanks again. I had to mark below answer as right, as only 1 can be marked right but I upvoted your answer too.